# Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase and have the following schema for `users`:

```
{
     "uid": "randomUID",
     "domain": "@domain1"
}
```

and I have a collection `domains` containing all the domains of users like so:

```
{
    "@domain1": {
                    "uid": "randomUID"
                }
}
```

I'm trying to use Firestore security rules in order to prevent creation of new users that have the same domain as a pr-existing. This is what I have so far:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{Id} {
         allow read: if true;
         allow create: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/domains/$(resource.data.domain)) == false;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I've also tried the following combinations of the allow create rule but none of them worked:

```
if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/domains/$(resource.data.domain));
```

and

```
if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/domains/$(request.resource.data.domain));
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Debugging the security rules is tricky since there's no debugger yet.

Answer (score -2):

First, you cannot access `resource` without first accessing `request`. Then, when you're using

`if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/domains/$(request.resource.data.domain));`

you try to look for the domain of the user you are about to create. So far it may work. But are you sure the value of `request.resource.data.domain` absolutely equals to the path of the `domain` you've created?

Because if you did it using the `add(...)` method to add new domains, then those values won't be the same.